# How many surjections are there from a set of 3 elements onto a set of 2 elements?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I know we can use inclusion-exclusion principle or stirling numbers to solve this for a set of n elements onto a set of m elements. But I wanted to know how can we get the result using simple combinatorics as the number of elements here is too less.

Comment: Do you mean the numbers $3$ and $2$ are too small to evaluate [$2!\,\genfrac\{\}0{}32$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Surjective_functions_from_N_to_X)? Curious.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion _is_ simple combinatorics, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

You know probably the number off all functions from $\lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$ to
$\lbrace 1,2\rbrace$ and
a function which is NOT surjective must be constant since the range has only two elements.