# How many surjective function from a set of 3 elements to a set of 2 elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, functions

I know there are [many questions like this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188299/how-many-surjections-are-there-from-a-set-of-3-elements-onto-a-set-of-2-elements)

but I need a detailed explanation to the answer of this question:
"How many surjective functions from a set of 3 elements to one of 2 elements?"

I ask yet another question of this type because I was asked this question in my discrete math exam, and my (wrong) answer was:

$$2^3 -2$$
where $2^3$ is the total number of function (because I have 2 possible choices for each element of the first set) where I need to subtract the number of possible functions that can't be surjective that is 2, because taking as an example the two sets:
$$\{1,2,3\} \text{ and } \{A,B\}$$
and these 2 functions:
$$f(1) \to A \\f(2) \to B$$ the third element $3$ cannot "go" either in A nor in B, so the two unpossible surjective functions are $2$.

However that's wrong (or at least my explanation).
My professor told me that it is not the right motivation and that I do not understand what a function is, now I have to retake the exam and I need to know in detail what I should have said, thanks to those who will help me.

Comment: It's your explanation that's wrong.  The count is correct.  There are $2^3$ functions, ignoring the restriction.  Of these, exactly $2$ fail to be surjective (which are they?)

Comment: The two non surjective functions that you subtract are simply the functions $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)$, where the choice of $f(1)$ thus fixed $f$. Now there are two options for $f(1)$.

Comment: @Slugger so there are $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = a$ and $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = b$  right?

Comment: The two constant functions are the functions that are not surjective.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @lulu thanks a lot you'all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{a,b\}$. Then there are 2 possibilities for $f(1)$. Then, if $f(2)=f(1)$, there is 1 possibility for $f(3)$ and if $f(2)\neq f(1)$, there are 2 possibilities for $f(3)$. So, you have $2\cdot (1+ 2)=6$ possibilities.

Comment: Your answer should probably be $2\cdot (1+2)=6 =2^3-2$, the first $2$ comes from the two choices of $f(1)$.

Comment: @Slugger: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have three choices of what maps to $A$, and for each such choice, two further choices for what maps to $B$.
So, $6$ possible functions.

In general for a set with $n$ elements surjectively mapping to a set with $m \le n$ there are $n.(n-1)....(n-(m-1)) = n!/(n-m)!$